# Установить точку входа в NPM пакет

Tags: node.js, npm

Проблема такая. Опубликовал свой первый пакет в NPM. Когда я устанавливаю его с другого проекта и пытаюсь подключить он почему то автоматически ищет определенный файл в папке src/scripts и у меня получается следующее -

```
import МОЙ_ПАКЕТ from "МОЙ_ПАКЕТ/src/scripts/development.js";
```

при чем тут файл development.js, который лежит в папке src я не понимаю. В поле main package.json я указал необходимый мне путь (к папке dist). Это работает, но только если не использовать ES6 модули

```
const x = require('МОЙ_ПАКЕТ');
```

Это дает нужный результат. Но используя import он указывает полный путь до файла src/development.js, а не подхватывает dist/production.js. Как указать точку входа и для import тоже?

Comment: удалить и переустановить? покажи адрес пакета

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/page-scroll-indicator
удалял и переустанавливал не помогло

Comment: https://github.com/DenisLopatin/page-scroll-indicator импорт ES6 просто привязался к файлу src/scripts/development-page-scroll-indicator

Comment: а, теперь понятнее. вот это -> https://github.com/DenisLopatin/page-scroll-indicator/blob/main/src/scripts/main.js <- не модуль. отсюда НЕЧЕГО импортировать и реквайрить

Comment: а вот отсюда https://github.com/DenisLopatin/page-scroll-indicator/blob/main/src/scripts/development-page-scroll-indicator.js есть чо. IDE сильно умная и сама знает где она может подхватить "модуль" :)

Comment: Да, но дело в том что у меня в папке dist находится точка входа, которая отсутствует на гите просто. Например require подхватывает именно его, этим объясняется то, что вызов функции уже произошел и плагин выполнился со стандартными параметрами (первая ссылка) и есть возможность подхватить функцию и настроить ее (вторая ссылка)

Comment: но даже если оно все и так то почему именно при ES6 import webpack устанавливает длинный путь к файлу - import developmentPageScrollIndicator from "page-scroll-indicator/src/scripts/development-page-scroll-indicator"; а не import developmentPageScrollIndicator from "page-scroll-indicato";

Comment: Кстати говоря папка dist в гите не отсутствует)) вот мне короче говоря нужно его получать КОРОТКИМ путем. Как import $ from 'jquery' - как они это делают?))

Comment: у них есть `module.exports` https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js, а у тебя - нет. т.е. в dist/page-scroll-indicator.js у тебя лежит "скрипт", который выполнится один раз при подключении

Comment: Дельный совет, но к сожалению не помогло. Возможно что то не так делаю. module.exports стал возвращать пустой объест

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118534/discussion-between-denis-lopatin-and-norbornen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка входа в npm пакет определяется в файле `package.json` в поле `main`. После этого можно будет использовать имя пакета в загрузках `import МОЙ_ПАКЕТ from "МОЙ_ПАКЕТ";`

В данном случае многое будет зависеть от типа модулей использованных при сборке npm пакета. Рекомендуется собирать в UMD, так как они совместимы и с CommonJS и с ES модулями. Я собирал всегда в CommonJS и без проблем использовал их с ES модулями, но если собрать как ES модули, то можно столкнуться с проблемой при подключении их с помощью require (но это не точно).

В данном случае `const x = require('МОЙ_ПАКЕТ');` подхватывал точку входа, так как она была указана в `dist/prod`, а `import МОЙ_ПАКЕТ from "МОЙ_ПАКЕТ/src/scripts/development.js";` ссылался на имя экспортируемого файла МОЙ_ПАКЕТ, который был экспортирован из `/src/scripts/development.js`. Игнорируя точку входа по причине минификации файла в `dist/prod`. Он утратил оригинальное имя МОЙ_ПАКЕТ, которое было заменено сборщиком на М_П. И он просто искал сопоставление при импорте.